# Laravel 5.3 response()->download - File(.doc, .docx) becomes unreadable after downloading

Tags: laravel, local-storage, laravel-5.3, doc

**Laravel 5.3**

When I download a file (.doc, .docx) from my storage folder it becomes unreadable. If I go to the local folder and open the file however it is valid and readable.

I am using the standard download function, using headers and stuff.. Have a look at my code:

```
$fileNameGenerate = 'example_filename';
$fileArr = [ 'wierd_filename', 'docx' ];
$cvPath = storage_path('app/example_folder/subfolder/wierd_filename.docx');

$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/' . $fileArr[1],
);

try {


    return response()->download($cvPath, $fileNameGenerate . '.' . $fileArr[1], $headers);


} catch (\Exception $e) {
    //Error
    return redirect()->back()->with('error', trans('locale.file_does_not_exists'));
}
```

Does anyone know what is wrong here? Thank you!

**Update:** I removed headers, it doesn't work with or without them.

Here is how the files render in the 2 different cases:

[image: The second file - gone wrong]

Comment: Did you try printing $fileArr[1] and making sure it does give correct Mime type?

Comment: There's no need to set the header. You're telling the browser to download the file, remove that.

Comment: @Rahi, yes the array is correct. Actually is doc, not docx, but it should still work:

array(0 => "c58ae31d925e486953c5f029bfcf8916", 1 => "doc")

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, I actually set the header in attempt to fix this issue. It is not working that way either

Comment: Is there any difference with or without headers?

Comment: @Rahi - no no difference. I removed them

Comment: Open file in text editor (or better hex editor). What are the first two symbols? Is it \r\n?

Comment: @shukshin.ivan , No. I have one empty space. This is the first symbol, followed by PK.
Take a look at the screenshot: 
http://image.prntscr.com/image/7b898bc8f14d4d5ea70e1d9e1a82c43e.png

Comment: PS - the php file that calls the function is in UTF-8 if this has any importance. Could it be something related to Encoding incompatibility ? Also why at all this function manipulates the file? Is this for security or something?

Comment: Do you have one space in the output when placing `exit();` before return? Strange thing.

Comment: @shukshin.ivan  No. placing exit(); does not output any spaces - when inspecting, the body cannot be expanded at all. I have however some shadow root stuff between the html element & the site head, which is something that Chrome does I found out. Tested it on Firefox and IE - the issue persist there too..

Comment: Look at network activity, tab Response. If it contains a space, looks like something is adding a space. Accidentally added space at the bottom of a file after `?>` ?

Comment: I did not close the php tag at all actually. I will also have to test with several different files and see what happens

Comment: Any news? Did you fix it?

Comment: @shukshin.ivan, not yet. I will update this post when we identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
public function getDownload()
{

//doc file is stored under storagepath/download/info.docx

```
$file= pathofstorage. "/download/info.docx";   

return response()->download($file);
```

}

Comment: No, this does not work. The file is not downloading at all, if I call this function from other function. If I change my routes to this function it starts the download and again - the file is unreadable

Answer (score 0):

I added:

```
ob_end_clean();
```

before:

```
response -> download
```

and it worked for me.